# TreeView how to create one that would look like onse that are used in VS appearence?

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

Is there a standart win form component that would look like such treewiew: [image] or any tutorial on creation such one?

Comment: I wasn't expecting that image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is not a treeview, this is simply the PropertyGrid and you can reuse it directly from the .NET Framework check here in MSDN:

[PropertyGrid Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx)